# vim --remote-tab and line number

Tags: vim, vi

Question is simple.

First I do:

```
$ gvim +239 file.txt
```

and get `file.txt` opened on line `239`.

But if I do:

```
$ gvim +239  --remote-tab file.txt
```

then I get `file.txt` opened on first line, option `+239` does't work. How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments are out of order:

```
$ gvim --remote-tab +239 file.txt
```